# Problem in running eclipse from the shortcut in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: eclipse

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 on my machine and i recently installed eclipse on it. Well, from the command line it is running fine but when i made shortcut for it on desktop it is giving me error something like this

> "A Java Runtime Environment or Java Development Kit must be available in order to run eclipse. No Java Virtual Machine was found after searching the following locations: /home/aaaaa/eclipse/jre/bin/java
>   Java in your current PATH".

I have set PATH environment variable very well and i have also tested "javac" and "java" command through terminal. They both are working fine. Now in order to make my shortcut work what setting i have to make additionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a script for it, or if one is provided, link to that.

In your script you can export path before executing eclipse.

I'm not sure what the name of the eclipse jar is, but you can put in your script the explicit path of the java executable (/usr/bin/java), and have it run eclipse that way.

Comment: Did exactly what you said but still the same problem is there..

Comment: But i have already specified the JDK path in PATH Environment variable then why i need to do that? Can't it directly take by reading environment variables?

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya: yes, it can in theory, but just sometimes it doesn't get picked up when it's being run from a launcher for some reason - so to make life easier.......

Comment: so what steps i have to follow exactly ? I have made script but the last point that you said i am not getting it. How i have to provide path of java executable explicitly?

Comment: Yeppi, Problem got solved. Just followed the steps written on the http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini. All i had to do was to provide  jvm path in eclipse.ini path.